# Is it possible to use return for a string in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

I am trying to run the code below. However, I use `return`, it does not work. If I use `println`, it works.  I need to use `return` because this function will be stored in another variable. So I wonder, is the code wrong or I simply cannot use return for this.

```
def checkos(longName) {
    if (longName.contains('Windows Server 2008')){ 
        return 'Windows Server 2008' } 
    else { return null }
}
checkos('Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise')
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: If I use return:
The output I expect : Windows Server 2008
The output I get:

Comment: please edit your question and provide function definition that you have

Comment: return doesn't print anything anywhere. It just... returns a value to the caller function, which can then use that returned value the way it wants to.

Comment: even if I called the function, put the result in a variable and print the variable, no output yet

Comment: Update: the code is correct, for some reason, I still do not understand, it doesn't run in Visual Studio Code IDE ]. However,  it works on Groovy playground https://groovy-playground.appspot.com/   thank you all for your help.